# Run a downloaded program using ssh tunnelling

Tags: xfce, ssh-tunneling

I have a remote Ubuntu server (version 16.04) and I have established a ssh tunnel using

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username server_ip_address
```

in my local machine. To set all the configuration files I have followed the guide in this link
[Install and configure VNC on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I had no problems following all the steps of the configuration.
The desktop environment is xfce4 and the vnc server is tightvnc.

On the remote server I installed the simulation program `Netlogo` 64 bits version suited form that machine. The problem is that I am not able to run the executable. With VNC client I can run in the server programs already installed like Firefox but when I double click on the icon of the Netlogo program nothing happens. The permissions of the program has the box "Allow this file to run as a program". I have tried other desktop environments but then the remote session looks encrypted and I cannot see anything with VNC.
The program is not running, I have checked from the Terminal.

I cannot guess what is the cause, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem was the Java version. Is a bug already reported with a shot solution as explain in [Know Issues:NetLogo won't start on Ubuntu 16 (and various other Linux systems)](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Known-Issues)